# Spring implementation of CORS is not rejecting messages when I expected it to

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, configuration, cors

I have a Spring @RestController annotated web service in my maven project, and I want to add CORS functionality to it.  I have half-managed to do this, but I'm getting results that I don't expect.

The symptoms are that I send a message to my service from a port number of 1111 for example, but I have CORS enabled on the server with a configuration that I believed should reject 1111 ports, as I have 2222 let's say in the configuration.  My server's sat on 3333 port.

I'm using 5.1.1 versions of spring-web, spring-webmvc, spring-security-web, spring-security-config, and spring-context if that helps narrow it down.

Here's the very simple service;

```
@RestController
public class MyService implements IMyService {

    IMyReqHandler requestHandler;

    public MyService (IMyReqHandler requestHandler) {

        this.requestHandler = requestHandler;
    }

    @PostMapping("/dothings")
    public void DoThings(@RequestBody MyMessageType msg) {

        requestHandler.processRequest(msg);
    }
}
```

My current config is as follows;

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class CORSConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.cors();
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {

        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:2222"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("POST"));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/dothings", configuration);
        return source;
    }

}
```

I have confirmed that the code is hit during startup.

The exact response headers are;

```
HTTP/1.1 200
Vary: Origin
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:1111
Content-Length: 0
Date: Fri, 23 Nov 2018 12:48:06 GMT
```

I expected the 1111 in the response headers to be 2222 because of my configuration.  Why isn't this the case?  What am I missing?

**EDIT:**  Apologies for misleading here, but turns out I'm getting those headers by virtue of another bit of code...  On the service's method I have the annotation;

```
@CrossOrigin(value = "http://localhost:1111")
```

That explains the 1111, but when I remove that line I get no CORS related headers added at all.  If I remove the value from it, I get CORS headers, but they are defaulted to "allow all", which isn't what I want.

I should add that I see no headers AT ALL related to CORS when I remove that offending line of code.

Why isn't my configuration having any effect on my service calls?  I need a way to dynamically set the value...

Comment: From the duplicate:  I tried Hendy's answer first, doesn't work, I get exceptions about "NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.ObjectPostProcessor<?>' available".  As you can see the answer from dur was already tried (see OP), and the one from AntonIva does not work either, that's to do with OAuth.  None of those answers work.  Have updated question to reflect that.

Comment: This question has had a major edit.  It was turning into a blog post of failures, so I stripped it down to the essence of my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the CORS control is present. The CORS control is done based on the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header on the respose and the Origin header sent on the request. If they both match you're allowed to call the resource.

When you use a tool (different form a browser) to call your resource, generally no Origin header is added. Or is added the Origin header with the same domain/ip of your resource.

The Spring Security CORS filter sends no Access-Control-Allow-Origin header when the request is made from the same domain of the server or the request is made from a domain that is not in your allowed origins (setAllowedOrigins). Because the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is not present the browser only allows request from the same domain.

If you call the service from a domain on your allowed origins (setAllowedOrigins) the Access-Control-Allow-Origin will be return on the response with the name of the domain on the Origin header.

**TEST**

I did the test with the same server and 2 different ports (9797 and 9798)

This is my config class

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
            .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:9798")
            .allowedMethods("POST", "GET")
            .allowCredentials(true).maxAge(3600);
    }
}
```

These are the response headers

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:9798
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Date: Wed, 28 Nov 2018 14:07:08 GMT
Expires: 0
Pragma: no-cache
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Vary: Origin
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
```

I invoked the service in localhost:9797 from a page on localhost:9798 as you can see the header **Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:9798** is present. (They are 2 requests, one with OPTIONS and one with POST) If I invoke the service from a page on http://localhost:9797 the **Access-Control-Allow-Origin** header is not present but I can call the service without a problem.

Comment: I'm using Chrome to test this, so it should be honouring the CORS stuff.  But, when I receive the response from server, it contains no info at all about CORS, and the request fails.  "when the request is made from the same domain of the server" <-  Do you think it might be because the addresses only differ by port?  The browser sees it as different domains, but Spring sees it as the same and so doesn't add the response headers?  Or is that a red herring?

Comment: I've made a slight edit to question to hopefully be more clear

Comment: @DanRayson Do you think it might be because the addresses only differ by port? yes, a different port means a different server/domain in CORS. I did a test but with jsfiddle. I will do another test with the same server different ports

Comment: @DanRayson I changed my example on the answer, I removed the corsConfigurationSource bean from the configuration and I added a new class WebConfig that implements the addCorsMappings method. This method has the cors config.

Comment: It doesn't seem to make much difference, I get a 403 response with this and your previous example.  The response headers are simply not set, even though I see the CORS config firing up in the server's output at startup.  I think both may actually be correct but something is making this fail elsewhere perhaps.  There's no other config I can find regarding CORS or request filtering, so I'm a little lost.  I think I'm going to have to give up on Spring's version of this and just use a Filter and manually do it. :(  I really appreciate your time spent on this, if that's any consolation lol

Comment: I'm wondering if I should mark this as the answer, even though I cannot verify it.  You say you've tested it, and it could be helpful to others.  Thoughts?

Comment: I uploaded a test to GitHub https://github.com/reos79/spring-cors so you can check it.

Comment: @DanRayson it has a html page (person.html) this page does nothing but call the service on the port (9797). So you need to load this project twice, once on port 9797 to load the service and the other on port (9798).  Then on you browser you call the page person on the server localhost:9798 and it will call the service on localhost:9797, in the file application.properties I configured the port.

Comment: I will have to check this tomorrow - I'll get back to you!

Comment: I have tested your implementation and it works perfectly.  I'm going to use it as a guide to re-create my other project, eventually I'll be able to find where I went wrong.  Your solution works, and your answer will be useful to others I'm sure.  Marking as accepted.  Nice one!